# ChromeWebDriver IJavaScriptExecutor to get script value?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a strange issue with ChromeDriver v75.0.3770.140 when I try with a url below to return a script value, and it returns a null value.

```
   var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.6pm.com/p/adidas-team-issue-ii-sackpack-white-jersey-black-clear-lilac-purple/product/9045515/color/749092");

    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    var val2 = js.ExecuteScript("return window.zfcSessionId"); // work fine
    var val = js.ExecuteScript("return window.__INITIAL_STATE__;"); // nullreference
```

Comment: Does it matter that you have semi-colon on end of the second js.ExecuteScript line string?

Comment: @BrandenHuggins no, it's still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm):

> The ExecuteScript(String,Object[] )method executes JavaScript in the
>   context of the currently selected frame or window. This means that
>   "document" will refer to the current document. If the script has a
>   return value, then the following steps will be taken:

- For an HTML element, this method returns a `IWebElement`
- For a number, a `Int64` is returned
- For a boolean, a `Boolean` is returned
- For all other cases a String is returned. For an array,we check the first element, and attempt to return a `List<T>` of that type, following the rules
  above. Nested lists are not supported. If the value is null or there
  is no return value, null is returned.

In your case, `__INITIAL_STATE__` is a `JSON` object that does not meet any of the returning types above.

Instead of getting the JSON object from the web page, try to get the serialized string in the C# code (by executing `JSON.stringify`):

```
var val = js.ExecuteScript("return JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__)");
```

In this case, the return value is string. From here, you can deserialize it using:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(val);
```

Comment: thanks for your input, yes that works fine. However, I still have no idea why the Json object did not work out as I've been using it for months.